# Disable changing of border-color with given class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If add "Orange" before "Orange" that is `readonly`. The `input` that will have red borderline is the `input` that is read-only w/c is wrong. I dont want the `read-only input`(supposedly from database to be mark as duplicate or to have red borderline)

**Current output:**

```
Apple [read-only]
Orange // *added by user*
Orange[read-only] //borderline changed to red when button save is clicked
```

**Wanted output:**

```
Apple [read-only]
Orange // *added by user* and borderline changed to red when button save is clicked
Orange[read-only]
```

See this [FIDDLE for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8y54wwuj/4/) and try to click add row button before the row with "Orange" value input field with another "Orange" value of input.

```
$("#save").off("click").on("click",function(){
    var existing = [];
    var duplicates = $('#myTable td:nth-child(3) input').filter(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (existing.indexOf(value) >= 0) {
            return $(this);
        }
        existing.push(value);
    });
    duplicates.closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

I tried this :

`duplicates.closest('#myTable td:nth-child(3) input:not(readOnlyText)').css('background-color', 'red');`

but nothing change.

Comment: This is bound to happen as per your code. You need to differentiate between rows added by user from already existing ones. You can add a class/attribute to rows added by user and then apply your filter.

Comment: @VivekKumarBansal  I alreay add a class for read-only input but when i try to do this   duplicates.closest('#myTable td:nth-child(3) input:not(readOnlyText)').css('background-color', 'red'); , no changes

Comment: What you basically want is if there is any duplicate value in Name then that row/s should be marked as duplicate

Answer (score 1):

This is bound to happen as per your code. You need to differentiate between rows added by user from already existing ones. You can use readonly attribute to rows added by user and then apply your filter.

```
$("#save").off("click").on("click",function(){
    var existing = [];
    $('#myTable td:nth-child(3) input').filter(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if ($(this).attr('readonly')) {
            existing.push(value);
         }
    });
    var duplicates = $('#myTable td:nth-child(3) input').filter(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (existing.indexOf(value) > -1 && !$(this).attr('readonly')) {
            return $(this);
        }
    });
    duplicates.closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: When I click on `Add Row` in first row and type `Orange` in second and click `save`. Second row is highlighted. Isn't that you wanted?

Comment: sorry, on that case, your code works fine, but if i try to add two consecutive row with same "Berry" values for example, I want also to detect the last part to be duplicate or if he input three consecutives "Berries" i want the second and third to have red borderline.